# Como mostrar una escena y regresar al flujo normal del juego en Unity

Tags: unity

Cuando un jugador realiza bien una actividad del juego, se le debe mostrar una pantalla de felicitación. Después de mostrarla, el flujo del juego debe regresar a donde se quedó.

¿Cómo lo hago? Estoy usando Unity.

Ya intenté con corrutinas, pero no me carga la escena.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que propones es muy simple, puedes hacerlo usando un contador que a su vez active o no un `if`. Te lo explico por código.

```
public class SuccessfulScreen : MonoBehaviour {

    private float count;

    public float timeToWait; // Tiempo (seg.) que quieres la pantalla de éxito activa 
    public GameObject screenToView; // El GameObject de la pantalla de éxito
    [HideInInspector] public bool successfulActivity; // Variable a la que llamarás (true) cuando necesites activar la pantalla

    private void Update() {

        if (successfulActivity) {
            // Acciones que necesites ejecutar
            screenToView.SetActive(true); // Se visualizará la pantalla
            // FIN Acciones que necesites ejecutar

            // Contador para esperar X tiempo
            count += Time.deltaTime; // Aumentará el valor de "count" en cada refresco de pantalla
            if (count >= timeToWait) { // Si "count" supera el valor fijado en "timeToWait"
                // Acciones
                screenToView.SetActive(false); // Se ocultará la pantalla
                // Fin Acciones

                // Reinicio de valores
                successfulActivity = false;
                count = 0;
                // FIN Reinicio de valores
            }
            // FIN Contador
        }

    }
}
```

Para que funcione correctamente debes tener varias cosas en cuenta:

1. Tienes que crear un nuevo Script llamado `"SuccessfulScreen"` y
   copiar/pegar este código dentro.
2. Incluye este nuevo Script en un objeto vacío de la escena donde
   siempre esté activo.
3. Necesitas crear tu pantalla de éxito agrupando todos los elementos
   de esa pantalla en un objeto padre.
4. Este objeto padre tienes que desactivarlo por defecto. Si no lo
   haces se visualizará desde primer momento.
5. Asigna este objeto padre en la variable publica `"screenToView"` de
   este Script.
6. Asigna un tiempo (en segundos) a la variable `"timeToWait"` de este
   Script.
7. Incluye dentro de los comentarios `//Acciones` y `//FIN Acciones` la
   funcionalidad que necesites ejecutar, como para el tiempo de juego,
   bloquear el movimiento del jugar, lo que requiera tu juego.
   Acuérdate de que el primer bloque de `//Acciones`, es para ejecutar
   la funcionalidad que necesites y en el segundo bloque, es para
   volver al estado del juego antes de que se vea la pantalla de éxito.

Para llamar a esta clase y hacer que se ejecute, tienes que usar este código en el script que quieras llamarlo:

```
public SuccessfulScreen scriptSuccessfulScreen;

private void Update() {

        scriptSuccessfulScreen.successfulActivity = true;
}
```

En el Script donde incluyas este código, tienes que asignar el GameObject, donde esté el Script `"SuccessfulScreen"`, a la variable publica `"scriptSuccessfulScreen"` en el inspector de Unity.

Ten en cuenta que la línea de dentro de `Update()` solo se tiene que ejecutar una vez, por lo que queda en tus manos organizar tu código cumplir esto.

Este código es mejorable, pero dado que no sé cómo es tu estructura de proyecto ni tus Script, es lo que puedo ofrecerte. También tengo que decirte que el código no está probado, por lo que, si tiene algún error, coméntame.

Espero que te sirva.

Mucha suerte.

Comment: Excelente solución, te lo agradezco mucho